# How to retrieve SQLCODE using javax.persistence

Tags: hibernate, informix, entitymanager, sqlcode, jpa

I am using the `EntityManager` from `javax.persistence` to do some operations on a informix database. For example:

```
public void execute(String sql) {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

I need the SQLCODE returned by this execution. Do you have any hints for me on how to achieve this?

Edit: I found out that it is possible to use SQLCA (SQL Communication Area). Has anyone experience with that?

Comment: Why do you need the return code? "executeUpdate" will throw an exception if the update fails. otherwise it worked well.

Comment: My product owner want's this. All executed sql's are stored in a database table. One column is provided for the sqlcode..I think he want's to differ between the various sqlReturnCodes...

Comment: i would write something like that:

public void execute(String sql) {
int returncode=0;
try {
    Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(sql);
    query.executeUpdate();
}catch(sqlException e) {
returncode = e.getErrorCode();
}
}

Comment: There is no such exception thrown by the entityManager...

Comment: But executeUpdate can throw a RuntimeException. http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#executeUpdate--

Comment: Throws:
    IllegalStateException - if called for a Java Persistence query language SELECT statement or for a criteria query
    TransactionRequiredException - if there is no transaction or the persistence context has not been joined to the transaction
    QueryTimeoutException - if the statement execution exceeds the query timeout value set and only the statement is rolled back
    PersistenceException - if the query execution exceeds the query timeout value set and the transaction is rolled back

Comment: Yes, but they got no getErrorCode()-method.

Comment: perhaps there is a sqlexcecption in the cause of the runtimeexception? the sql exception has a method getErrorCode. .... sorry I have no other idea

Comment: Yeah, that would be possible, but it is really ugly...I need to cast and check for instanceOf and stuff and I need to rethrow the exception, because I wan't my program to abort in such a case.

Comment: Yes it is ... but I don't see another solution. Sorry.

Comment: I think I found another way: look my edited post.

Comment: The SQLCode can be obtained from the `SQLException` that was thrown by the driver. But apparently your obfuscation layer does not let you access that.

Comment: Yes, it is hidden deep inside the cause. But I found out, that it is possible to ask the db for the error code. I just don't know how to do this.